# Mask specific elements in a final layer in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am now reproducing the following model which outputs an `action` and uses `filter` for filtering inappropriate candidates. 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03274

In this model, output is filtered after last softmax layer. Let's assume `action_size==3`. So the output after dense & asoftmax layer is like below.

```
output: [0.1, 0.7, 0.2]
filter: [0, 1, 1]
output*filter: [0, 0.7, 0.2]
```

But in pytorch, `logsoftmax` is preferred with `NLLLoss`. So my output is like below. This doesn't make sense.

```
output: [-5.4, -0.2, -4.9]
filter: [0, 1, 1]
output*filter: [0, -0.2, -4.9]
```

So pytoroch doesn't recommend `vanilla Softmax`. How should I apply mask to eliminate specific actions?
Or is there any categorical cross entropy loss functions with vanilla Softmax?

> This module doesn’t work directly with NLLLoss, which expects the Log to be computed between the Softmax and itself. Use Logsoftmax instead (it’s faster and has better numerical properties).
>   http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Softmax

Answer (score 0):

The output of LogSoftmax is simply the log of the output of Softmax. That means you can just call `torch.exp(output_from_logsoftmax)` to get the same values as from Softmax.

So, if I'm reading your question correctly, you would calculate LogSoftmax, and then feed that into NLLLoss and also exponentiate that to use in your filtering.